# How to unwrap a list from typesafeconfig list to the list of particular type?

Tags: json, scala

I have a config in json format  and I am using Typesafe Config library to load this.

Input config in json format

```
 {
  "input": {
   "Date": "2014-01-01",
   "Ids": ["1","2","3","4"]
    }
 }
```

Code

```
  import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
  val config = ConfigFactory.load("test.json")
  val ids = config.getList("input.Ids").unwrapped
  #  ids: java.util.List[Object] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

All I am getting is list of object. When I try to do a map of each element to int it fails because each element is an object.

```
   ids.map(_.toInt)
    <console>:14: error: value toInt is not a member of Object
          ids.map(_.toInt)
```

How to convert the object list to integer list in scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getStringList` method and then map the result to int

config.getStringList("input.Ids").map(_.toInt)

or in this case use the `getIntList` method directly